# Can I take a case of wine transiting through Dubai?

Tags: transit, dubai, alcohol

I'm flying from South Africa to Paris in September for a wedding. The groom is into wine, so I'll thought to give the couple an assorted case (12 bottles) of South African wines. Can I take the wine through Dubai as checked baggage? I would only have a 5 hour layover so I won't be leaving the airport.

From past experience, I know that checking baggage through to the final destination often doesn't work, so I'm also worried about trundling round the airport with it.

I'm also aware that 12 bottles is over the tax free limit for most countries, and will be declaring the wine when landing in France, but not in Dubai.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's checked luggage, there should be no issue. You're in transit, not entering the country.

If you were entering the country, however, you'd need to be aware of the limit of [4 liters of alcoholic beverages](http://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/eServices/ServicesForTravellers/CustomsDuties/Pages/PermittedItems.aspx) as your limit of wine, according to the Emirates Customs website.

This is [also confirmed on the Dubai Airport website's page](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/security-customs).

If it's in your carry-on, however, you'll have issues as you're limited to 100ml per liquid, but checked luggage should be fine.

Comment: The 100ml limit doesn't apply to [duty free in the special bags](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45815/3221). Though I don't believe that's what he is bringing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton correct, this was more just to cover if he was considering taking them in the cabin from South Africa.